# Cloning over http: "does not appear to be an hg repository"

Tags: http, mercurial, iis-6

Running Windows Server 2003 with IIS6, trying to clone a Mercurial Repository through HTTP. All my directories are readable and writable and executable for everyone. Yes, that is not wise, but still it is not possible to clone my repository over HTTP.

I get the message that this does not appear to be an hg repository.

Comment: There is not a lot of info, so I'm just guessing. If you are using `hg serve` as server, do not forget to put exact port to clone command `hg clone http://localhost:8000`

Comment: How are you serving up your repository? You say "through http", but what does that mean? Are you using `hg serve`? If not, what are you using?

Comment: tnx for replying. I gave up on IIS6 and a using apache now, but with new problems. Got much further though. But I will express my problems in another thread.